# Outlook NewMailEx for shared folder

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, shared-directory

I got a shared folder. I need to change the messageclass based on the address, but how can I process mails which are in the shared folder?

This seems to be a good solution: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/0bba3c22-7703-4083-8d55-73bd5230af22

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NewMail/NewMailEx events only fire on the primary mailbox.

On any other store or folder you will need to use Items.ItemAdd event.